# Ubuntu Mate Mate 20.04: No Down Bar to show me what programs are open

Tags: .desktop, executable, caja

Nothing appears in my down bar. What have I've done? There were some errors and I clicked "ok". Now, nothing appears on my down bar anymore (except trashcan), even after restart. Thanks!

Comment: What errors exactly?

Comment: Wish i could tell you. I thought the usual "some errors occorred. do you wanna send?". But there was something about windows also, as I have Wine installed. Is there a way to review those errors? The bell in the top bar does not help. Thanks!

Comment: Is it Ok if I uninstall and reinstall Caja from Synaptic?

Comment: Bu then again, the program works. it just doesn't register in the "below" bar. All other programs also.

Comment: Launch MATE Tweak and reset panel layout to Traditional.

Comment: This fixed the problem! The programs are now in the "down bar" again. Thank you, N0rbert!

Comment: You may want to start referring to (and edit the question accordingly) to "dropdown menu" instead.

Comment: Thank you, but AskUbuntu won't let me add "dropdown menu" as a tag. N0rbert solved it just fine as it was.

Answer (score 1):

Launch MATE Tweak (`mate-tweak`) and reset panel layout to Traditional.